# Need to assign an CheckBox to the end of the text in pdfbox

Tags: java, pdfbox

I need To generate a checkbox in PDFBox. The Problem while I was generating is that the CheckBox should be assigned to every question in the PDF next to the text. I was able to set the checkbox positions for one type of questions, but when it comes to generating the other model type with the other questions it should be adjusted again. I needed something which can automatically adjust to the question generated.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Is your problem finding the correct coordinates for adding an image? Then please make clear wheat your criteria are and what kind of image you want to position.

Comment: My usage of this PDF is to generate question from the DB with options (yes, no ) checkbox next to the question. Simply Saying it's like exam questions which needs options next to the question.

Comment: Do you want that checkbox as an actual form element? Or just a graphic presentation, i.e. just a square?

Comment: just a graphic presentation which with variables on top of it which says yes or no.

Comment: for example: I found some source which is similar pattern to what I should generate but with much longer data of questions. I need that to generate yes and no check boxes along with the text up on  it. https://tsattachmentstorage.blob.core.windows.net/tspreviewthumbnailcontainer/b5e9d9eedae4493abbbf4133392ba4d7/891d3deeebd44f30ba50611c02aaa7e9/Preview/4351095e56ab4a0398c5f2b0a60fc5df/Thumbnail/d2145acaa5574e079322fe90b27ea1b9/8F34E57971DD8D03D049C6129D481D263A8845097EFC371E73637EF9C9E16520.png

Comment: Does this mean you want radio buttons? I.e. where either the "yes" or the "no" button is activated, and the text "yes" / "no" near each of these buttons? There is an example about radiobuttons in the `CreateRadioButtons.java` example in the source code download.

Comment: I am not using for the editable  PDF, I just need that to just show the checkbox so that they can print the questionnaires and check the checkbox with pen.

Comment: Then just draw a rectangle, or use a rectangle symbol in some font. Try the built in Symbol or Zapf Dingbats type 1  font.